# Can I extend a mapped resource with same name declared in separate terraform config

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Let's say I have below `tf config` in `first.tf`.

```
resource "google_service_account" "deployer" {
  for_each = { for p in google_project.projects : p }

  project      = each.key
  account_id   = "dep"
  display_name = "ABCD"
}
```

I also have another file named `second.tf` having

```
resource "google_service_account" "deployer" {
  for_each = { for q in google_project.new_projects : q }
    
  project      = each.key
  account_id   = "dep"
  display_name = "Look at for each"
}
```

I am using same resource name(dictionary for_each version) and willing to store different projects in `second.tf`, but could not.

It throws below error:

> A google_service_account resource named "deployer" was already
> declared.

Is it possible to extend or overwrite any already defined resource(s) in the current run?

Comment: No you can't. It would lead to issues if one tf script overwrote something that other tf script did. Why not use different names? Or if you use the same name, why you are trying to "create" it from two script files?

Comment: This is notably possible in another major declarative DSL: Puppet. However, even in that case it only allows attribute overrides at a lower scope for a resource shadowed at a higher scope, and it also does not allow re-declarations. This is a same scope re-declaration.